# Fluent Nhibernate - One to Many Mapping Issue

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I am getting NHibernate.MappingException while trying to do one-to-many mapping in fluent nhibernate.
Below are the snippets from my entity and their mapping classes:

```
public class ReportRequest : IReportRequestToBeFullyLoaded
{
    public virtual Int32? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<ReportOutputEmail> ReportOutputEmails { get; set; }
}

public class ReportOutputEmail
{
    public virtual string RecipientAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual ReportRequest ReportRequest { get; set; }
}

public class ReportRequestMap : ClassMap<ReportRequest>
{
    public ReportRequestMap()
    {
        Table("ReportRequest");
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(null).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Description);
        HasMany(x => x.ReportOutputEmails).Table("ReportOutputEmail")
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_ReportOutputEmail_ReportRequest")
            .KeyColumn("ReportRequestId")
            .AsSet()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class ReportOutputEmailMap: ClassMap<ReportOutputEmail>
{
    public ReportOutputEmailMap()
    {
        References(x => x.ReportRequest)
            .ForeignKey("FK_ReportOutputEmail_ReportRequest")
            .Column("ReportRequestId");
        Map(x => x.RecipientAddress);
        Map(x => x.Message);
    }
}
```

There is some issue with one-to-many mapping between **ReportRequest->ReportOutputEmail**,
Getting error:

```
Error: NHibernate.MappingException: (XmlDocument)(3,6): XML validation error: The  
element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element  
'property' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements  expected:  'meta, subselect, cache, synchronize, comment, tuplizer, id, composite-id' in     namespace  'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.
```

Can anyone help figuring out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ReportOutputEmail` doesn't have an identity, it'll need one if its going to be an entity.

Also, I recommend you upgrade your copy of Fluent NHibernate, as this is reported in a much more helpful manner since 1.1 (you'd get an identity missing message).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can't I do without a separate Id for ReportOutputEmail? Becuase what I want is just ReportRequest.ReportRequestId to identify records in ReportOutputEmail.

Comment: You've specified the `ReportRequest` can have many `ReportOutputEmail`. You can't use `ReportRequestId` as a primary key, because there's potential for multiple records to have the same value.

Comment: Thanks! just came to know that this is by design in NHibernate. If your table doesn't have a key of any kind, then it isn't an entity.